# I do not understand why `touch -h` is not working as documented in the man page on macOS Big Sur

Tags: command-line, big-sur, bug

The default `touch` utility on macOS Big Sur does not respect the `-h` flag.

If one wants to use the `-h` option as claimed in the `man` pages of Apple, one has to use the GNU version of `touch`.

Is there a way to update `touch` to a newer version that respects what is written in its `man` pages?

I am using macOS Big Sur, with APFS, fully up to date as of 2021-08-15. The default `touch` has man pages written in 1995.

Here is an example of what happens:

```
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff  9 Aug 14 10:10 testfile
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  staff  8 Aug 14 10:11 testfilelink@ -> testfile
$ touch -h testfilelink
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 xxx  staff  9 Aug 14 10:15 testfile
lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxx  staff  8 Aug 14 10:11 testfilelink@ -> testfile
$
```

Comment: How does touch not work? The source code is at https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-321.100.11/touch/touch.c.auto.html and does deal with -h

Comment: I see the same effect as the OP. Standard touch, M1. https://gist.github.com/nohillside/3da8bb5ad7561484c525d808290500ed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems you have found a bug in macOS. The next-to-last major version of the operating system works according to the manual paage, but the latest version does not.

Either the manual page is outdated, or the software has a bug (most likely).

You can send feedback to Apple as a general user here:'

https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Or if you are a developer, you can use the Feedback Assistant to file a bug report as described here:

https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/

There's currently no newer version of `touch` available from Apple so you cannot as such upgrade your way out of the problem. As you indicate yourself, you can instead use the GNU version of `touch` to get the job done. You can find that in Homebrew by installing `coreutils`.

The GNU version of `touch` works by calling the newer `futimens()`/`utimensat()` functions (in the latter case with the `flag` argument set to `AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW` to change the timestamp for the link itself).

The Catalina version of `touch` ([287.100.2](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-287.100.2/touch/touch.c)) works by calling the older `lutimes()` function, which explicitly sets the timestamp on the link itself. One of the core differences between the newer and older APIs are that the newer supports timestamps in nanoseconds, whereas the older has a lower resolution.

The `lutimes()` function on Big Sur actually doesn't implement a system call itself, but is actually contained fully in the standards library, using the `setattrlist()` function (which results in a system call) to actually perform the file system modification. `setattrlist()` is highly file system dependent (i.e. how it works on HFS+ file systems would be different from how it works on APFS file systems).

The Big Sur version of `touch` ([321.100.11](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-321.100.11/touch/touch.c)) works by calling the `setattrlist()` function directly, and only if that fails, fall back to `lutimes`. Unfortunately, it seems the programmer forgot about the need to specify that when `-h` is specified, the modification must take place on the link itself.

The actual bug is in line 219 of [touch.c](https://opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-321.100.11/touch/touch.c), where this line:

```
if (!setattrlist(*argv, &ts_req, &ts_struct, sizeof(ts_struct), 0))
```

should have been:

```
if (!setattrlist(*argv, &ts_req, &ts_struct, sizeof(ts_struct), utimes_f == lutimes ? FSOPT_NOFOLLOW : 0))
```

You could change that in touch.c, recompile it, and get a working binary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was thinking about it and I am happy to see that several people comfort me in the fact that it seems to be a bug and that I should report it.

Comment: Ah yes - looking at the source code I found the bug in Big Sur's version now... I'll update the answer.

Comment: Regarding compiling `touch.c`. On a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** 11.5.2 on a **Intel** based **Mac**, I had to first install **Commend Line Tools for Xcode** and then used the following _command_ afterwards: `cc touch.c; sudo mv -nv a.out /usr/local/bin/touch` which returned `a.out -> /usr/local/bin/touch`. I then ran `file /usr/local/bin/touch` and it returned just `Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`. This is fine for my usage, however, what _command line argument_ is necessary to compile it so `file` reports: `Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:...] [arm64:...] ...`?

Comment: @user3439894 `cc touch.c -o x86_app -target x86_64-apple-macos10.12; cc touch.c -o arm_app -target arm64-apple-macos11; lipo -create -output touch x86_app arm_app`. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary

Comment: Excellent analysis!  I think my answer should be removed.